# Is it possible to make a Confluence Search + Redirect Script which works based on URL/tags in the url

Tags: redirect, search, tags, wiki, confluence

I would like to write a plug-in which fetches all the pages addresses/titles (or other identifiers) and redirects the user based on some input string probably a tag in the URL. Does making this sort of plug-in sound feasible? Alternatively, does this plug-in already exist?

I imagine an external script sends the user to "myconfluencewiki.com/redirectme#funnycats". From here the script looks through the wiki and finds "myconfluencewiki.com/fun/funnycats" and sends the user there instead. It does this by finding the title so that it works even if the page was originally on "myconfluencewiki.com/animals/funnycats".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some add-ons for redirections: [Redirection](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/net.customware.confluence.plugin.redirection), [Advanced Redirection](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.hascode.confluence.plugin.redirection-plugin) or [HomePage Redirect](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/ch.bitvoodoo.confluence.plugins.homepageredirect).

If you still needs to develop your own add-on, the "[path converter](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-plugin-guide/confluence-plugin-module-types/path-converter-module)" module can be handy.

Regards,
Gorka